# jsonp - internet explorer and loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jsonp

I have a problem with using jsonp with internet explorer.

My code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'my url',
    cache: false,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
        i = 0;
        for (var ix=0;ix<data.length;ix++) {
            item = data[ix];
            v = item['value']
```

On chrome eveything is ok, I loop over data and get all my values "v".

On internet explorer I get the correct data but when I iterate, "item" is wrong. "data" is correct, "ix" is correct but "item" is incorrect.

If I look data I have a list with items containing s "value".
But "item" is something strange with "[prototype]", "arguments", "caller" and "prototype".

Do you have an idea ? Thank you

Comment: Can you show the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`?

Comment: Hello, You can see the script here: http://actecil.fr/agenda-des-formations/

Comment: The output is printed in the console.

The output in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/LVeHvsvR

Comment: There's no `value` property in any of the objects there.

Comment: The first one looks like `{"location":"Marseille","formations":[{"dates":["Mardi 16 Mai","Mercredi 17 Mai","Jeudi 18 Mai 2017"],"sectors":["Généraliste"],"wordpress_page_id":"catalogueformationscnil/catalogue-des-formations-cnil-formations-labellisees-par-la-cnil/cil","formation":"Formation Labellisée : Exercer le métier de correspondant Informatique et Libertés","logo":"https://tools.actecil.fr/media/actecil_intraapps/formation/2016/11/label-actecil-formation-CIL.png","formation_id":2}]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved,

I use and it is ok

```
$.each(data, function(k, item) {
```